# How to link dict with dynamic keys to sqlite3

Tags: python, json, sqlite, dictionary

I need expertise on how to link a dynamic key to a sqlite3-db.
Currently the resulting db from my approach will be empty after execution.

````
        ```python
    import requests
    import json
    import sqlite3
    
    # establishing DB and sqlite3
    connection = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    # getting data from the API and directly to the key I´m interested in (level)
    url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=FX_INTRADAY&from_symbol=EUR&to_symbol=USD&interval=5min&apikey=demo"
    res = requests.get(url)
    alphadata = res.json()
    level = alphadata["Time Series FX (5min)"]
    
    # Structure = {"TIME Series FX(5min)": {Dynamic Timestamp: {"1. open": value,"2. high": value,"3. low": value,"4. close": value}
    start = sorted(level.keys())
    next = level.values()
    
    # I figured out how I can increase in a loop the index-number of 'alphadata' (0-99) and print out the result
    for i in range(len(start)):
        attempt = alphadata["Time Series FX (5min)"][start[i]]
        d1 = list(attempt.values())[0]
        d2 = list(attempt.values())[1]
        d3 = list(attempt.values())[2]
        d4 = list(attempt.values())[3]
        print(i+1, start[i], d1, d2, d3, d4)
        
    
    # I guess I have to link SQLITE3-DB here somehow to the above index-table, but how? I tried it the following way resulting in an empty DB:
    sql_instruction = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eurusd (
            id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
            "Date" TEXT,
            "1. open" REAL,
            "2. high" REAL,
            "3. low" REAL,
            "4. close" REAL
        ); """
    cursor.execute(sql_instruction)
    connection.commit()
    
    for i in range(len(start)):
        attempt = alphadata["Time Series FX (5min)"][start[i]]
        d1 = list(attempt.values())[0]
        d2 = list(attempt.values())[1]
        d3 = list(attempt.values())[2]
        d4 = list(attempt.values())[3]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO eurusd VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (i+1, start[i], d1, d2, d3, d4))
        connection.commit()
    
    
    # complete list of time and values incl. keys for control-purposes
    # for start, next in level.items():
        # print(start, next)
````

Does someone know how I could approach the insert to a sqlite3-db, because of the depending dynamic key which is obviously based on the time of request of the API?
I would highly appreciate if someone could advise here.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried the code and the database is not empty.

Comment: I tried again without any editing and it is working. I have no idea what changed....
Thank you!